# Using a Node JS library with QML

Tags: javascript, node.js, qml

I want to take a JS library designed and packaged for Node.js and use it with QML (specifically the [ProtoBuf library](https://github.com/dcodeIO/protobuf.js/blob/master/dist/protobuf.js)). The ProtoBuf library relies on the [ByteBuffer library](http://github.com/dcodeIO/bytebuffer.js).

I edited `bytebuffer.js` and `protobuf.js` to add `.pragma library` as the first line. Then, in my `.qml` I have:

```
import "qrc:/scripts/bytebuffer.js" as BB
import "qrc:/scripts/protobuf.js"   as PB

Window {
  Component.onCompleted: {
    console.log('PB',  PB);
    console.log('func',PB.loadProtoFile);
    for (var k in PB) console.log(k,typeof PB[k],PB[k]);
    console.log('done!')
  }
}
```

The output I see is:

```
qml: PB [object Object]
qml: func undefined
qml: done!
```

So, QML is loading the ProtoBuf library in some sense (and I've put debug messages in that library and confirmed that the [generic loader](https://github.com/dcodeIO/protobuf.js/blob/master/dist/protobuf.js#L29) is running and able to find `ByteBuffer`), but it's not an object with the [methods that I expect](https://github.com/dcodeIO/protobuf.js/wiki/Getting-started), like `loadProtoFile()`.

How do I get to the ~real `ProtoBuf` object that the library exposes? Or how should I modify the libraries to work with QML properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand now that the way QML namespaces libraries, the statement

```
import "qrc:/scripts/protobuf.js" as PB
```

causes `PB` to be the global scope in which the library script was run. As such, the 'real' ProtoBuf that the library exposes in this code:

```js
(global["dcodeIO"] = global["dcodeIO"] || {})["ProtoBuf"] = factory(global["dcodeIO"]["ByteBuffer"]);
```

can be found in QML as:

```js
var ProtoBuf = PB.dcodeIO.ProtoBuf;
console.log( ProtoBuf.loadProtoFile );
//-> function() { [code] }
```